# Error while Calling methods for objects stored inside a ArrayList

Tags: java

I have declared an **ArrayList** to **store my objects** of the **class Books**.

```
static ArrayList<Books> bookData = new ArrayList<Books>();
```

So I have multiple methods inside class Books. Let's say I have a method named...
**getName()**, Let's assume I have objects stored inside ArrayList and I want to **call the method for the object stored** in the array list.

So Is this correct:

```
bookData[1].getName();
```

or

Is this correct:

```
bookData.get(1).getName();
```

If the first is wrong, then why? Is there a method to call the object stored inside `ArrayList`?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: The first one is the syntax for an array and the second one is for arraylist. So the first one will not work for the arraylist.

Comment: An array is a **language construct**, and its elements can be accessed by using `[index]`

Comment: And just so that I could sleep well, can you please change the class name from Books to Book in your code, so that you could have a proper array of objects Book (long shelf). Thank you. (Unless you planned on building a custom bookcase)

Answer (score 4):

```
bookData[1].getName();
```

This is incorrect because the `[1]` syntax only works for an array. It does not work with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: OK, Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

for Arraylist you can use only

```
bookData.get(1).getName();
```

bookData[1].getName(); is used only with Array and Not with Arraylist